# Queue set of AJAX requests and execute response data in one

Tags: jquery

I have a set of nested Ajax calls which retrieve various data from a server, and change a group of page elements based on the structure of such data, possibly executing more calls and changing even more elements, all in order to generate a new view for the user:

```
$.ajax(
    //...
    function() {
        if(x) {
            $('#element').html('...');
        } else {
               $.ajax(// more similar changes, more ajax)
        }
    }
)
```

Currently, the above code causes the elements to be re-drawn sequentially. However, I would like for all the redrawing to happen all at once - at least from the users perspective - so that the user experiences nothing but a smooth transition to the new view, not seeing the individual renderings.

How could I achieve this?

Comment: I removed the [jQuery Animate] and [jQuery Deferred] tags from your question as I think they're irrelevant. Also made the title appear more readable and searchable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**IF NOT DEPENDING ON SPECIFIC RESPONSES FROM EACH REQUEST**

jQuery has a `.when()` and `.done()` function that, in your case, would perform all AJAX requests first, and when all requests are complete, you can do something with all the response data in one go, so the user doesn't witness a staggered transformation as different AJAX requests complete at different stages.

```
$.when(ajax1(), ajax2(), ajax3(), ajax4()).done(function(a1, a2, a3, a4){
    // the code here will be executed when all four AJAX requests complete
    // a1, a2, a3 and a4 contain lists of 3 items; the response text [0],
    // the status [1], and an jqXHR object [2] for each of the listed AJAX calls
    $('#element1').html(a1[0]);
    $('#element2').html(a2[0]);
    $('#element3').html(a3[0]);
    $('#element4').html(a4[0]);
});

function ajax1() {
    return $.ajax({
        url: "someUrl.php",
        dataType: "html",
        data:  myData,
        ...
    });
}

function ajax2() {} // same as above
function ajax3() {} // same as above
function ajax4() {} // same as above
```

For further information on using `.when()`, and to learn how to error handle the AJAX calls, check the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/).

**IF YOU ARE DEPENDING ON SPECIFIC RESPONSES FROM EACH REQUEST**

You could store each response and the element ID into an array and work on them in one go later, when all AJAX calls are complete. Something like this could help (using your code from above):

```
var myAjaxResponses = [];
$.ajax(
    //...
    function() {
        if(x) {
            myAjaxResponses.push({
                'elementID': "element1",
                'responseData': x,
            });
        } else {
            $.ajax(
                function() {
                    if (x) {
                        myAjaxResponses.push({
                            'elementID': "element2",
                            'responseData': x,
                        });
                    }
                }
            )
        }
    }
)

// loop through myAjaxResponses
// adding the response data to each respective element
function processResponses() { // called when last AJAX request finishes
    $.each(myAjaxResponses, function (index, value) {
        $('#'+value.elementID).html(value.responseData);
    });
}
```

Here is a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6kb9a/1/) to show the array idea working.

Comment: I do depend on them unfortunately - they calls are nested, and are generated depending on the outcome of each poke at the server. I thus cannot know which or how many Ajax calls will be invoked in total when I invoke the top of the chain - hence why I would need a way to gather them all before I do the rendering.

Comment: @chrsva; Oh okay, never mind. I'll leave this answer here as it may help others. Another suggestion; you could store each response in an array `{elementID,responseData}` and when all AJAX calls are complete `$(document).ajaxStop(executeMyResponses())` loop through the array adding each response data to the respective elements.

Comment: @chrsva I've added an extension to my answer that has my array suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Chrsva, I can envisage three options :

1. Accumulate the piecemeal data client-side and act on it once it is complete.
2. Compose the entire data set server-side, deliver it in one hit then act on it.
3. As it arrives, act on the piecemeal data by updating clone(s) of the relevant DOM fragment(s), then bank-switch the DOM when all data has been delivered.

Which option you choose will depend in part on what you have already written. From what you say in the question, the most attractive option is proably #3.

Your biggest problem may be determining when the data gathering is complete.

Comment: Could you not use `.ajaxStop(function(){})` to determine when all AJAX calls are complete and then bank-switch the DOM?

Comment: I've never needed to use `.ajaxStop()` and would be concerned that, in this usage case, it might fire prematurely but it's worth trying.